# How to prove Cauchy-Schwarz inequality using a given hint

Tags: proof-writing, vectors

I have to prove that $|v\cdot w|\leq\Vert v\Vert\Vert w\Vert$.

I was given the following hint:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n(x_iy_j-x_jy_i)$$
but I've never seen this expression before and have no idea how to use it in the context of this proof.

So far I've tried rearranging the inequality to
$\Vert v\Vert\Vert w\Vert \cos(x)\leq\Vert v\Vert \Vert w\Vert$
but this hasn't really helped me.

Any help to understand the expression I was given in context of the proof would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the fact that $| cos(x)| \leq 1$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField This is more or less trivial purely algebraically. Otoh to do what you said you need to first prove that $x\cdot y=||x||\,||y||\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Could you give us more context about the hint given? (Posting the original source might help us understand the problem better)

Answer (score -2):

First square both sides and expand using definition:

$$ |v \cdot w |^2 = (v \cdot w )^2 = (v_1 w_1 + v_2 w_2 + \dots + v_n w_n )^2 $$

and

$$ (\| v \| \| w \|)^2 = (v_1^2 + \dots + v_n^2)(w_1^2 + \dots + w_n^2) $$

Now you can expend the 2 and hopefully see the result.  I have to leave for a second but will return to finish my answer